# String lookup failed on Iteration over a list using pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, loops, dataframe, contains

I have a list of strings I am trying to search through a pandas DF column with  and delete any rows containing an element of that list.

Here is the code to search a specific column, then remove a row containing a substring of text in quotes. In this case, all rows containing 'dave' in the Owner_Name column would be removed. this works great by itself, exactly as expected.

```
df = df[~df.Owner_Name.str.contains('dave')
```

When I try to automate this over a list of 54 or so elements, it gets hung up and only removes some, but not all. Any idea why? 
Here is my simple code for the loop(mock up to show what I am doing, not my actual code):

```
badWords= ['random stuff','code words','secret squirrel','blue','black','dave']
for word in badWords:
    df = df[~df.Owner_Name.str.contains(word)]
    print('Total Rows Left',df.shape[0], word)
```

I am not getting any errors, but it certainly isn't working like I would want. For example, after the loop, there are still 'dave' elements around in the Owner_Name column, even though it supposedly looped through the list. I even put breadcrumbs to call out the element being passed, so it is doing the loop, but it is as if the str.contains('') is not working properly to remove the rows. I made sure to make everything match the case of my list objects also in the df, so that shouldnt be an issue. I am really stumped and cant find anything on stack about this specific issue.

Comment: try `df = df[~df.Owner_Name.str.contains('dave', regex=False)` if the string is exact match. also `case=False` if looking for case insensitive

Comment: Thanks anky, for whatever reason the case = False worked. I had applied this tot he data frame column to try and take care of that: df['Owner_Name'].str.lower()

Obviously it didnt work. Thanks again for the quick answer!

Comment: Welcome. I have added the answer that worked so people can follow later, please feel free to edit if required. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer here which worked:

```
badWords= ['random stuff','code words','secret squirrel','blue','black','dave']
for word in badWords:
    df = df[~df.Owner_Name.str.contains(word,case=False)]
    print('Total Rows Left',df.shape[0], word)
```